# Video show on Edit Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, audio, video

Hi there I am having a problem here if someone can help me please..
I am saving image on storage  and on edit(update) view(blade) for that I do it like this:

```
<img src="{{url('/')}}/images/questions/{{ $question->id }}/medium/{{ $question->question_image }}" class="answer-image-create" id="question_image_box">
```

and it works fine, because the image is saved  good like an image on the storage folder, but with audio and video in storage is saved with a lot of numbers the file looks something like this, for example videofile.mp4 :

```
4944 3303 0000 0000 0000 fffb 9240 0000
0000 004b 0500 0000 0000 0960 a000 000b
2987 3c19 4880 0965 30e7 8329 1001 f19b
12cd dc1b 1006 8caf 8011 311b f804 9014
fed2 d805 814a 7db3 a165 04e9 07ff c2e6
0500 3204 4cc3 ffc9 c1c6 e813 eaff fcd0
66c8 b95c 8a11 434f fffc c8b9 271a b4d5
ffff f97d 2412 4190 4cdd 93ff ffff fd33
4410 2fa6 91c0 08fc 66c4 b377 06c4 01a3
2be0 044c 46fe 0124 053f b4b6 0160 529f
6ce8 5941 3a41 fff0 b981 400c 8113 30ff
f270 71ba 04fa bfff 3419 b22e 5722 8450..
```

I tried something like this to show the video but it is not working:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" preload="none" controls>
  <source src="{{url('/')}}/video/questions/{{ $question->id }}/original/{{ $question->question_video }}"  type="video/mp4">
```

Any idea..?  Thank you.

Comment: {{storage_path().'/video/questions/'.$question->id.'/original/'.$question->question_video}}
try this

Comment: No it does not work...

Comment: This is how it looks with inspect element
<source src="http://localhost:777/myproject/public/video/questions/435/original/f0d0cd609f5ecce28ede0b207b4c8339" type="video/mp4">

Comment: where you store your videos

Comment: in storage folder or public?

Comment: storage/app/public/..

Comment: Store your videos in  /public/video  instead of  /storage/app/public/video. Then link video using `src="{{ asset('video/questions/{{ $question->id ') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this by adapting the structure of your folders:

**You get the video from a route:**

```
Route::get('/videos/questions/{id}/original/{quetion_video}', [ 'as' => 'video', 'uses' => 'VideoController@viewVideo' ]);
```

**In your controller:**

```
function viewVideo($id, $quetion_video)
{
    $filename = storage_path() . "/videos/questions".$id."/original/".$quetion_video.".mp4";
    $headers = array(
        'Content-type' => 'video/mp4'
    );

    return Response::make( file_get_contents($filename), 200, $headers);
}
```

**In your view:**

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="{{ route('getVideo', [ 'id => '$question->id, 'question_video' => $question->question_video ])  }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It's the idea of what you have to do, you can get examples and explanations here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/how-to-let-user-play-audio-and-video-files-stored-in-directory-above-public

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/getting-video-from-storage-directory?page=0

https://laravel.io/forum/02-14-2016-how-read-uploaded-video-files-from-storage-directory